# postgreSQL replication is out of sync

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

i hope that can u solve my problem. I'm kinda new with replication services of postgreSQL. I have to take this from other person.

Here is what i know, i have three servers,  one main (A) and other two are slaves (B and C).

Main server, have wal_archive directory with all files up to date.
[image: Main server wal_archive]
B server has out of sync data and stopped syncing (last data is 2018-09-03), while C server is syncing data perfectly fine (last data is 2018-09-19 and up).

Syncing stopped on B server, when on main server A, i recreated materialized views, so C server managed to refresh changes, other B tried and stopped.
Here is error log from `cp: cannot stat '//var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/archive/00000001000001F8000000AC': No such file or directory
2018-09-16 06:25:20 EEST [27606-1] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 1F8/AC000000 on timeline 1
2018-09-16 06:25:20 EEST [27606-2] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000001F8000000AC has already been removed`

What should i do on server B? Should i just stop and restart psql process, and he will manage to rebuild itself or other choises, less painful?

Comment: This really belongs to DBA site.

Comment: It is possible to answer someone to my question?

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask the same question on https://dba.stackexchange.com, people on that stack exchange site are more knowledgeable on this subject. You're basically have better odds to have your question answered there.